# Network requests and responses are stay in the memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, memory-dump

I'm using AFNetworking as my basic networking class. When I do a memory dump on a jailbroken phone, I can easily see request urls or responses(like json objects) in the dump files in plain text. I checked with the leak tool in xcode and there is no memory leak based on that. My app has sensitive data in the urls or responses(Like user's name, email address...), I want to clean those information right after the connection finished.

I tried disable the NSURLCache in the app:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0
                                                        diskCapacity:0
                                                        diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

I also tried:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

or

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];
```

But none of these works.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If you are doing a memory dump you will see the remains of deallocated Foundation objects because they do not wipe memory on deallocation so they remain until the memory is re-used. There is no real general solution other than some how not using Foundation types. Apple does not provide secure versions of `NSString` and `NSData`. File a bug report requesting secure Foundation objects: http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: You should consider using `AFHTTPSessionManager` and use `initWithSessionConfiguration` with an ephemeral session. See `ephemeralSessionConfiguration` reference in the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` documentation.

Comment: Why do you care if the user can see their own info on jailbroken devices? They chose to break the security of their device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```

Also you need to disable cache from your server-side script's header response. If it's in PHP:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Apple respects the response headers well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.